# Extract children's Array values into single array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to build a query which let me extract a list of arrays from documents with parent child relationship.

So I can use this array in find query.

Query doesn't have to be just mongodb, it can be typescript based.

**Question**

When I search `{ "itemGroupName": "PARI" }`, I want to extract its `childrenGroupList` and all its children's `childrenGroupList` values into a single array.

```
    [{
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64c62f8b312e0601c656cae3"
      },
      "itemGroupName": "PARI",
      "alias": "001",
      "parentGroupName": "",
      "hsn": "",
      "taxCategory": "",
      "status": {
        "active": true
      },
      "childrenGroupList": [
        "DREAMS PARI"
      ],
      "__v": 0
    },

    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64c62f98312e0601c656caea"
      },
      "itemGroupName": "DREAMS PARI",
      "alias": "002",
      "parentGroupName": "PARI",
      "hsn": "",
      "taxCategory": "",
      "status": {
        "active": true
      },
      "childrenGroupList": [
        "DREAMS PARI 001",
        "DREAMS PARI 002"
      ],
      "__v": 0
    },

    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64c62fb1312e0601c656caf2"
      },
      "itemGroupName": "DREAMS PARI 001",
      "alias": "003",
      "parentGroupName": "DREAMS PARI",
      "hsn": "",
      "taxCategory": "",
      "status": {
        "active": true
      },
      "childrenGroupList": [],
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64c63ffb6ecb0dcc1ee71555"
      },
      "itemGroupName": "DREAMS PARI 002",
      "alias": "004",
      "parentGroupName": "DREAMS PARI",
      "hsn": "",
      "taxCategory": "",
      "status": {
        "active": true
      },
      "childrenGroupList": ["DREAMS PARI 002B"],
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64c63ffb6ecb0dcc1ee715654"
      },
      "itemGroupName": "DREAMS PARI 002B",
      "alias": "005",
      "parentGroupName": "DREAMS PARI 002",
      "hsn": "",
      "taxCategory": "",
      "status": {
        "active": true
      },
      "childrenGroupList": [],
      "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using Mongo's [$graphLookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/). It allows for recursive lookups, which is exactly what you're looking for.

Like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "itemGroupName": "PARI"
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$childrenGroupList",
      "connectFromField": "childrenGroupList",
      "connectToField": "itemGroupName",
      "as": "result",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      childrenGroupList: {
        $setUnion: {
          $map: {
            input: "$result",
            in: "$$this.itemGroupName"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UGosDlHDyAo)

Comment: This worked like a charm :D 
I am currently using basic mongoDB commands so this was pretty advance stuff for me. 
Thank you for showing me the path for what  i should learn next in mongodb.